# spring security taglib loading error in freemarker page

Tags: spring-security, freemarker

I want to display conditional contents for anonymous or authenticated users. so I have to use spring security tags to check the visitor is authenticated or not. Since I am new to freemarker, I've googled on that keyword "spring security freemarker" and nothing helpful to me.

So here my question is,

- how to load spring security taglib in freemarker?
- any example on <sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()"> or "isAuthenticated()" ?

And I...
have added below tag into my freemarker view, but it gives me some error stack in the web browser.

```
<#assign  security=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"] />
```

[error stacks] - that I cannot clarify what is the cause...

```
   FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!): Error while looking for TLD file for "http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"; see cause exception. ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: #assign security = JspTaglibs["http:/... [in template "template.ftl" at line 2, column 1] ---- Java stack trace (for programmers): ---- freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...] at freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory.get(TaglibFactory.java:248) at freemarker.core.DynamicKeyName.dealWithStringKey(DynamicKeyName.java:140) at freemarker.core.DynamicKeyName._eval(DynamicKeyName.java:75) at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:81) at freemarker.core.Assignment.accept(Assignment.java:134) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:326) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:332) at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:305) at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:378) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:368) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:285) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:235) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:167) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory$TaglibGettingException: No TLD was found for the "http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" JSP taglib URI. (TLD-s are searched according the JSP 2.2 specification. In development- and embedded-servlet-container setups you may also need the "MetaInfTldSources" and "ClasspathTlds" freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet init-params or the similar system properites.) at freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory.get(TaglibFactory.java:222) ... 94 more
```

so please help me by answering my questions. thanks.

**EDIT: CASE CLOSED**

I had to manually import tld files. The cause came from that. Here's working code.

**Add maven dependencies**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Create a class**

```
public class ClassPathTldsLoader  {

    private static final String SECURITY_TLD = "/META-INF/security.tld";

    final private List<String> classPathTlds;

    public ClassPathTldsLoader(String... classPathTlds) {
        super();
        if(classPathTlds.length == 0){
            this.classPathTlds = Arrays.asList(SECURITY_TLD);
        }else{
            this.classPathTlds = Arrays.asList(classPathTlds);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadClassPathTlds() {
        freeMarkerConfigurer.getTaglibFactory().setClasspathTlds(classPathTlds);
    }
}
```

**add as a bean**

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ClassPathTldsLoader.class)
public ClassPathTldsLoader classPathTldsLoader(){
    return new ClassPathTldsLoader();
}
```

**fianlly declare below link**

```
<#assign  security=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"] />
```

I saw this workaround from multiple sites, so I do not know where the exact reference location is.

Comment: That stack trace is truncated (and has no line breaks). Maybe there's a cause exception that we can't see this way. So far it's only clear that it tries to load the TLD but that fails.

Comment: @ddekany thanks for replying my question, I updated my post with full error stack thank you.

Comment: So it says that it can't find such TLD: freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory$TaglibGettingException: No TLD was found for the "http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" JSP taglib URI. (TLD-s are searched according the JSP 2.2 specification. In development- and embedded-servlet-container setups you may also need the "MetaInfTldSources" and "ClasspathTlds" freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet init-params or the similar system properites.) at freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory.get(TaglibFactory.java:222)

Comment: Thanks for the clue! After dealing with pom, i will tell you the result

Comment: @ddekany Hi, i am sorry to late, I found a solution and it worked.  Thanks for the clue, if I were not have the clue, I didn't know where to start to resolve that.

Comment: Moral: Always check the cause exceptions in the stack trace. I have just copy-pasted the message of the cause exception shown there.

Comment: Easier solution: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/907#issuecomment-465388434

Comment: No TaglibFactory available. but that one was because servletContext = applicationContext.getServletContext(); configurer .setServletContext(servletContext); so applicationContext was not available for freemarker for configurer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better to use this one:

```
<#assign 
    known=Session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT??>
<#if kown>    
    <#assign
        user = Session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.authentication.principal
        name = user.getUsername()
        isAdmin = user.isAdmin()>
<#else>
    <#assign
        name="unknown"
        isAdmin = false>
</#if>
```

in your freemarker file for...

Comment: No TaglibFactory available. but that one was because servletContext = applicationContext.getServletContext();

            configurer
                .setServletContext(servletContext); so applicationContext was not available for freemarker for configurer.